# When two XCM's are processed in a block, how to strongly correlate balances.Deposit event with messageQueue.Processed event?

Tags: xcm

For this block: https://kusama.subscan.io/block/22144324, two XCM's are processed. The response is:

```
        "onInitialize": {
        "events": [
            {
                "method": {
                    "pallet": "balances",
                    "method": "Deposit"
                },
                "data": [
                    "FyE2tgkaAhARtpTJSy8TtJum1PwNHP1nCy3SuFjEGSvNfMv",
                    "150028590711"
                ]
            },
            {
                "method": {
                    "pallet": "balances",
                    "method": "Deposit"
                },
                "data": [
                    "GCNeCFUCEjcJ8XQxJe1QuExpS61MavucrnEAVpcngWBYsP2",
                    "78327426"
                ]
            },
            {
                "method": {
                    "pallet": "messageQueue",
                    "method": "Processed"
                },
                "data": [
                    "0x2e36da6586a9374d34d51c9753af445ea63d6672731ee7d25ac63738022978e9",
                    {
                        "ump": {
                            "para": "2001"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "refTime": "293037000",
                        "proofSize": "7186"
                    },
                    true
                ]
            },
            {
                "method": {
                    "pallet": "balances",
                    "method": "Withdraw"
                },
                "data": [
                    "F7fq1inJcCWWCd8sT26fdZkcozCsbJwYAwshtADXqCMGcjd",
                    "3230000000000"
                ]
            },
            {
                "method": {
                    "pallet": "balances",
                    "method": "Deposit"
                },
                "data": [
                    "Ecwo5t2LukeQjGjzVPK7khdjbnpFSxP2iTpjJBsezY8Exzy",
                    "3229921672574"
                ]
            },
            {
                "method": {
                    "pallet": "balances",
                    "method": "Deposit"
                },
                "data": [
                    "GCNeCFUCEjcJ8XQxJe1QuExpS61MavucrnEAVpcngWBYsP2",
                    "78327426"
                ]
            },
            {
                "method": {
                    "pallet": "messageQueue",
                    "method": "Processed"
                },
                "data": [
                    "0xe2d1652ebad3249e2559d96c7320f2bc6eac9bb1601e4c64b629bce0311b97a5",
                    {
                        "ump": {
                            "para": "2090"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "refTime": "293037000",
                        "proofSize": "7186"
                    },
                    true
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

In this array, it seems every XCM ends with a `messageQueue.processed` event. But is this always true? How do I strongly correlates one `balances.Deposit` event with one `messageQueue.Processed` event?

Comment: I guess a direction that could be taken is that, which sidecar api I could use to search this xcm id: `0xe2d1652ebad3249e2559d96c7320f2bc6eac9bb1601e4c64b629bce0311b97a5`?